# Border length - I need it from top to bottom

Tags: css

I have a page with fixed width and I am trying to put borders on it, left and right without success.

I know how to show borders but I cannot make them to reach the bottom of the page and stay there, unlees I set my divs to position:fixed which is not desired for my content div since I want it to scroll. is there a way to get around it?

Here is my css file (the code as shone below makes my borders go until 1/3 of my window even if I set body height:100%) - Thank you in advance:

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 1024px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    min-width: 50%;
    font-family: calibri;
    background-color: #999;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border-right: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-left: solid;
    border-left-width: 5px;
    border-color: #1d687b;
}

div#all {
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-right: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-color: #1d687b;*/
}

div#top {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 145px;
    background-image: url("images/bg_ttl.jpg");
    /*border-right: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;*/
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    /*border-left: solid;
    border-left-width: 5px;*/
    border-color: #1d687b;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

div#top_left {
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div#top_right {
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div#top_center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    width: 624px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    float: right;
    font-family: metalord;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div#left_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    float: left;
    width: 185px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
    border-right: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    /*border-left: solid;
    border-left-width: 5px;*/
    border-color: #1d687b;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#content {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 205px;
    width: 784px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
    /*border-right: solid;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-color: #1d687b;*/
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>arserus.com</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="all">
<div id="top">

<div id="top_left">
<span class="ttl_sd_l">
<img src="images/bttn_prpl.png" class="tl_txt" alt=""> network
 <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;& support
 <br />
 <br />
<img src="images/bttn_prpl.png" class="tl_txt" alt=""> creative ideas
 <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;& organization</span>
</div>

<div id="top_center">
    <span class="ttl_txt">ARSERUS</span>
</div>

<div id="top_right">
<div>
<span class="ttl_sd_r">
<u>e-mail:</u>
 <br />
info@arserus.com
 <br />
 <br />
<u>phone No. (cy):</u>
 <br />
7000 17 37</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="left_menu">
<div align="right">
 <span class="mn_lnk"><a id="p_home" class="lnk">home</a></span>
 <br />
 <br />
 <span class="mn_lnk"><a id="p_about" class="lnk">about us</a></span>
</div>
<div id="cp_rght">
 <span class="txt_cr">© 2012 ARSERUS</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<?php
require_once('p_home.php');
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML to go along with this CSS?

Comment: HTML code? Ideally as JSFiddle.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/ or google for `css full height layout`

Answer (score 1):

The old school answer to this problem is to use Faux Columns -

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

The idea is that you actually use a background image on your body element that is 1px tall, and as wide as you want, including the 'border' as part of the image, and to tile the image vertically.

True, it doesn't rely on CSS borders, and making changes involves image editing, but it *is* reliable.

For the most part, I've found approaching web design with the idea of a fixed height to be problematic, and I try to avoid it.

Comment: I did use html... It took the border to the bottom... BUT... It spoiled my content div overflow... it floads always, and when it does the border dosen't stay permantently at the bottom... If I scrol you can see the border going up

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is another css rule conflicting with your border rule. So what I would do to begin with, is:

1. remove all css rules.
2. apply your css border rule.
3. Re-add your other rule one at a time till the styles break over the problem rule.

This will narrow down the problem, and make the solution easier to find. 
Aside from that, you could try applying the border styles to the `<html>` tag. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah... my above comment it supposed to be here... sorry..>!

Comment: That's okay . :) Hmm, interesting. another hacky possibility would be to add 2 `<img>` of a line with a 800px? height, and use css to move them into position and then apply `position:fixed` to both. Don't know for sure it will work, but it's an idea.

Comment: ...ok. I solved the overflow. Just changed my (content div) from height:100% to height:auto. So my only problem now is to find out how to leave border in place when I have to scroll down.

Comment: Good work! I think the answer below would work the best for your border purposes. Messing with `position:fixed` can be tricky... :)

Comment: Well, the thing is, if you have to use something other than the css `border` rule, a `img` that is repeated-y is probably easiest to move into position.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7241/discussion-between-samstar-and-pavlos1316)

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting a static height:

```
height: 768px;
```

If you are looking to make a fluid (% - based) height scheme in CSS, that is really tough.  You might try using jQuery to get the window height and style your elements according to that:

```
var divHeight = $(document).height();
$('#yourDivId').height(divHeight);
```